# SDWebImage not working with Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdwebimage

I've read lots of posts regarding problems with SDWebImage and Firebase but none seem to solve my problem. I'm trying to display images from my Firebase storage in my collectiionView cells:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BildeKatCell

    let someUrl = URL(string: "url to one random firebase storage image")
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: someUrl, completed: nil)
    return cell
}
```

I have already made an array with the urls from all my images which i would eventually like to use instead, but I'm not able to display an image in my cell even with a hard coded url. I've tried all the different sd_setimage methods, and I've also tried doing the exact same thing in a normal viewController with a single imageView, I still get nothing. Don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the value of `someUrl`. Without that, it'll be hard to know what isn't working aboutit.

Comment: Did you try using the code that's provided in the [documentation](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/blob/master/Docs/HowToUse.md)? Also, for troubleshooting & testing, try populating a imageView without sd_setImage i.e. use built in swift code instead of a third party library.